# Scrapy Pagination Infinite

Tags: python, scrapy

i have a webscraping web project with Scrapy. And i have URL with a infinite Pagination. My start URL is : `https://nuevo.jumbo.cl/lacteos-y-bebidas-vegetales/leches-blancas?sl=3a356ef2-a2d4-4f1b-865f-c79b6fcf0f2a&PS=50&cc=18&sm=0&PageNumber=1&fq=C:/1/3/` , where the "PageNumber" is 1 to N Pages.
I put this in a for loop, for testing, in the parse function:

```
for i in range(1,100):
        yield FormRequest(
            url=self.base_url+o.path, 
            method="GET", 
            formdata={'sl':'3a356ef2-a2d4-4f1b-865f-c79b6fcf0f2a','PS':'50','cc':'18','sm':'0','PageNumber':str(i),'fq':fq}, 
            callback=self.parse_products,
            meta = {
                  'dont_redirect': True,
            })
```

But i need to do it without the for loop, because in "start_urls" i have many more with differnt "PageNumber".

So what i need is to go from PageNumber 1 to N, and when there are no more pages, stop that request.

I try with meta dont_redirect, because  when the spider not find more pages, i was redirecting to other page.
Y try with Middlewares, in **process_response()** i put:

```
if response.status == 301:
    raise IgnoreRequest
```

With that it does not redirect to another page, but it keeps trying to scan.

I need to do something like:

```
while(true):
    yield FormRequest #...etc etc etc...
```

Answer (score 1):

what i observe from the web behavior, [Products api](https://nuevo.jumbo.cl/buscapagina?sl=3a356ef2-a2d4-4f1b-865f-c79b6fcf0f2a&PS=18&cc=18&sm=0&PageNumber=5&&fq=C%3A%2F298%2F300%2F)

This is the api from where it gets the products, and Here `PageNumber` controls the pagination and `fq` controls the product categrory etc. but when the pageNumber exceed, it never give you redirection {I have tested it in postman} but a empty response, so check if the products are received in the api call, increment the page number otherwise stop. And change the `fq` [category]

Comment: thank you. I changed almost all the code, for something easier. Get the url, if response.body: +1 PageNumber, callback=self.parse